# Alert on browser close button but not for every load of the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want code to alert the user for closing the close button of the browser, but I am getting alert for every loading or for every refresh and tab change inside the web page.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Localstorage, cookies can be used!!!

Comment: How can we use cookies in java script to alert browser close

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the alert box state anywhere, so that you can check, if the user has seen it once. You could save the state of your alert box for example in a local storage. I changed the code. 
First on the onload event, check if there's a localStorage Item "showConfirmation". If not, create one with the string value "true", otherwise just log the value. 
Second, on beforeclose it checks if the item has the value "true". If so, return a string to show the alert message. 
Third, on window.close you set the item to string "false", the message will not be shown anymore.

```
window.onload = checkLocalStorage;
window.onbeforeunload = askForClose;
window.unload = checkLocalStorage;

function checkLocalStorage() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("showConfirmation") === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("showConfirmation", "true");
    } else {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("showConfirmation"));
    }
}

function askForClose() {
    var showConfirmation = localStorage.getItem("showConfirmation");
    if (showConfirmation === "true") {
        localStorage.setItem("showConfirmation", "false");
        return "You really want to close?";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,, But using this code not getting any alert message,, also for closing browser.

Comment: I changed the example to a working one. Maybe you have to test it with localStorage on a real domain.

Comment: ya i am testing with local storage only

Comment: Access to localStorage or sessionStorage will return in a SecurityError: `The operation is insecure.`

Comment: This SecurityError should be CORS related. So localStorage should be used on the same domain.

Comment: I Tried with above Code, But its working only for closing for the first time, later its not, and geting alert for every loading

Comment: What is the exact behavior you want to achieve? window.onbeforeunload will trigger on every page reload or page close / tab close, as long as you return a value other than null or undefined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: I am Trying to do Alert message only for Page Close and not for clicking some event inside the page(not for every reloading inside the page) and even for refresh of Page also alert should not come